# How to ignore skip locking for update for custom queries for in-memory database against junit test cases

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, junit, h2

I am writing junit test cases for which I have configured in memory h2 database. The functionality I am testing actually picks some records from database and do some processing over the records. When code pick records, it locks those records for update, so that no other process can access those records. This thing works fine but this is causing issue for test cases as I am using in memory db for test cases. How do I resolve this issue.

```
  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
  @Query(value = "select * from employee where account_id = ?1 limit ?2 for update skip locked", nativeQuery = true)
  public List<Employee> getEmployeesByAccountId(String accountId, Integer limit);
```

Please see above code, this is causing issue for test cases..

Error:

```
    Caused by:
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:151)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:2104)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2034)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2012)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:953)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2815)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2797)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2629)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2624)
        at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2123)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1134)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:173)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1526)
        at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:126)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:154)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:142)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:618)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
        ... 19 more

        Caused by:
        org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ACCOUNT_ID = ? LIMIT ? FOR UPDATE SKIP[*] LOCKED"; SQL statement:
        select * from employee where account_id = ? limit ? for update skip locked [42000-200]
            at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453)
            at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
            at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
            at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
            at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:229)
            at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:1051)
            at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:741)
            at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:657)
            at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:595)
            at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1235)
            at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:76)
            at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:352)
            at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:316)
            at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java)
            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:149)
            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176)
```

Thanks

Comment: looks like in memory `h2 database doesn't support that functionality

Comment: Any alternative???

Comment: try docker containers those are the best for integration test cases

Comment: Anybody any luck on this ? Facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I got a work around, its not solution but worked for me.

1. Created a Duplicate Repository Class in src/test package same as src without `for update skip locked` query.

   `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)`

   `@Query(value = "select * from employee where account_id = ?1 limit ?2 ", nativeQuery = true)`

   `public List<Employee> getEmployeesByAccountId(String accountId, Integer limit);`
2. So that whenever the Test case will execute it will execute the query from repository created in the test package.
3. It Served the purpose for me to test the single unit while processing.
4. Drawback is Junit test can not test the functionality of reading the same row at same time.